# How to login using openid with a script

Tags: ruby, openid

I'm trying to automate retrieving information from a website using OpenID login. How do I navigate the authentication process? Looking at libraries they seem designed to make use of, or be the openid server, rather than sit in the middle.

I imagine it involves.

1. Some request to the OpenID server to get a login token. The script will have the username/password hardcoded. I know, not ideal.
2. Cookies to send to the server to prove I'm logged in.

But I'm not really clear on the details of these two requests, or whether there would be more steps.